# WCF Data Service Error accessing SharePoint lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf-data-services, credentials

I am trying to access some SharePoint lists from a .Net (C#) web application. I googled the topic and it seemed the consensus was to use WCF Data Service (steps outlined below). After I get the data, I display it in a jQuery datatable, using Ajax web service call to grab the data.

Firt step was to run DataSvcUtil.exe to create a DataService.cs file that contains the client data service classes that are needed to access a data service from a .NET Framework client application. Then added references to Microsoft.Data.OData.dll and Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll. I created a we service API:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public string GetCompletedAssessments()
{
    SPService_DataContext dc = new SPService_DataContext(new Uri("http://my_sp_site_.com/sites/nvx/SPService/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"));
    dc.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var source = dc.CompletedAssessments;

    // I had to use the following, otherwise only 1,000 records would be returned; I had 16,000 records; 
    // this is also line 65 referred to in error trace
    var newSource = Utils.SelectAll(dc, dc.CompletedAssessments);

    string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newSource);
    return JSONresult;
}

public static List<T> SelectAll<T>(this SPService_DataContext dataContext, IQueryable<T> query)
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryContinuation<T> token = null;
    // this is also line 625 referred to in error trace
    var response = ((System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery)query).Execute() as System.Data.Services.Client.QueryOperationResponse<T>;

    do
    {
        if (token != null)
        {
            response = dataContext.Execute(token);
        }
        list.AddRange(response);
    } while ((token = response.GetContinuation()) != null);

    return list;
}
```

**My Issues:**

run locally, from within VS 2017, or from IIS on application server, I get all the data, albeit in 80 seconds (way too long for 17000 records). However when I run this from a browser, I get status code 500 error and can't see why.

Secondly, when I look at the error trace I see references to some files containing my development path. This is what I see:

```
error - 
Internal Server Error... 
Status: 500, 
ResponseText: {"Message":"An error occurred while processing this request.",
"StackTrace":" 
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)\r\n 
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()\r\n 
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.ExecuteInternal()\r\n 
at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery.Execute()\r\n 
at EA.BLL.Utils.SelectAll[T](SPService_DataContext dataContext, IQueryable`1 query) in C:\\Users\\yrtgn0\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\EA\\EA\\Controller\\BLL\\Utils.cs:line 625\r\n 
at EA.easg.GetCompletedAssessments() in C:\\Users\\yrtgn0\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\EA\\EA\\Services\\easg.asmx.cs:line 65","ExceptionType":"System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException"}
```

I can't figure out why the error pops up when i run this from browzser and not from within VS or IIS; and why the error shows my local path when I deployed the site after compiling and publishing it.

**Update**

I found out the reasn it was working from VS and IIS but not when accessed using proper URL after deployment was due to credentials. I was setting credentials to CrdentialCache.DefaultCrdentilas (later changed to DefaultNetworkCredentials) but had to use NetworkCrdentials(UserID, pwd, domain).

However, I was just testing it using my credentials which is not feasible. Now that I know what the cause is, can anyone provide an alternative to using this method to get around the issue?

Comment: anyone, any hints, pointing to some direction? Spent last two days and still can't figure out why this is happening. Googled the heck out of this and still nothing. Thought it might be a access issue since it works from within VS and IIS Manager but through browser using real URL.

Comment: I found what the real issue/cause was but still don't know how to resolve it. It is due to credential issue. Web application server and SharePoint server are on same domain but different servers and locations.